# Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $u=u(x,t)$ solution of following problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $u=u(x,t)$ solution of following problem:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_t=\frac{1}{2}u_{xx} & x \in \mathbb{R}  &, t > 0\\ 
u(x,0)=f & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Show that:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)e^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}dy$$

Comment: Is it correct to say that your $x-y$ and $y$ are [not mixed up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Some_Green.27s_function_solutions_in_1D)?

Comment: @BCLC hmm this how it is given in previous exams and I am exercising :(

Comment: Melina, is there some kind of symmetry? I tried substituting $u=x-y$. then later $y=u$ but it seems I ended up with negative of the integrand

Comment: @BCLC I am sorry what it is written in exam I wrote on question :S